# Exapansion of rows based on Calendar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My fact table is following

```
declare @fact as TABLE (WO varchar(3), startYear int, startFiscalPeriod int, endFiscalPeriod int)
INSERT INTO @fact
Select WO, startYear,startFiscalPeriod, endFiscalPeriod
from
(
VALUES
('WO1', 2020, 202011, 202106),
('WO2', 2020, 202009, 202106),
('WO3', 2021, 202102, 202106)

) t (WO, startYear,startFiscalPeriod, endFiscalPeriod)
select * from @fact
```

| WO | startYear | startFiscalPeriod | endFiscalPeriod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202011 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202009 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202102 | 202106 |

I want to expand the rows based on the interval between startFiscalPeriod and endFiscalPeriod, like following

```
;with cte as
(select WO, startYear,startFiscalPeriod, endFiscalPeriod from @fact
UNION ALL
select WO, startYear,startFiscalPeriod+1,endFiscalPeriod from CTE
where startFiscalPeriod<[endFiscalPeriod])
```

However, I want the expansion to happen based on a calendarTable.

```
    declare @Calendar as TABLE  (fiscalYear int, periodNumber int, fiscalPeriod int)
INSERT INTO @Calendar
Select fiscalYear, periodNumber,fiscalPeriod
from
(
VALUES 
(2020, 1, 202001), 
(2020, 2, 202002), 
(2020, 3, 202003), 
(2020, 4, 202004),
(2020, 5, 202005),
(2020, 6, 202006),
(2020, 7, 202007),
(2020, 8, 202008),
(2020, 9, 202009),
(2020, 10, 202010),
(2020, 11, 202011),
(2020, 12, 202012),
(2021, 1, 202101),
(2021, 2, 202102),
(2021, 3, 202103),
(2021, 4, 202104),
(2021, 5, 202105),
(2021, 6, 202106)
) t (fiscalYear, periodNumber,fiscalPeriod)
```

My desired output is following which I can't generate by simply expanding the rows on simple do while logic. Is there any way to condition the do while logic based on the calendar?

| WO | startYear | startFiscalPeriod | endFiscalPeriod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202011 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202012 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202101 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202102 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202103 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202104 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202105 | 202106 |
| WO1 | 2020 | 202106 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202009 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202010 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202011 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202012 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202101 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202102 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202103 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202104 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202105 | 202106 |
| WO2 | 2020 | 202106 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202102 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202103 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202104 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202105 | 202106 |
| WO3 | 2021 | 202106 | 202106 |

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not join the two tables with a between condition, like `Calendar.fiscalPeriod between fact.startFiscalPeriod and fact.endFiscalPeriod`?

```
select
    f.WO
    , f.startYear
    , c.fiscalPeriod startFiscalPeriod
    , f.endFiscalPeriod  
from
    @fact f
    inner join @Calendar c on c.fiscalPeriod between f.startFiscalPeriod and f.endFiscalPeriod
order by
    f.WO
    , c.fiscalPeriod
```